# What are these mysterious things in defining methods?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Back to development after spending some years in a management position, I am dealing with a PHP code, which has some definitions that I cannot understand (looks like I am far beyond of PHP progress on these years). Can someone let me know what campaignDTO and ParamDTO do in this definition?

What will be returned from this method?

```
/**
 * Creates a campaign
 * @param campaignDTO $campaign
 * @param ParamDTO $param
 * @throws \Exception
 * @return campaignDTO
 */
public function createCampaign(campaignDTO $campaign, ParamDTO $param)
{
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Read about [type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) aka "type hints".

Comment: ^ *Type Hint* was always a bad name though ... it's not a *"hint"* - a *"hint"* wouldn't make your application fall over - it's a requirement :P

Comment: How about taking a look at http://www.phptherightway.com for a start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type declarations as per docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a
>   certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect
>   type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable
>   fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so you mean there should be a class named "campaignDTO" somewhere in the code? Question 2, Is it possible to use a namespace instead of a class for data type?

Comment: Yes, there should be a class with that name... As for namespaces, see docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: I cannot find any class in the entire project with that name... What else can be used as a type?

Comment: It might not have its own source file, might be in a common file with many other class. Especially when it is a interface or ancestor class, and some of its implementer or child classes are within the same file.

Answer (score 0):

These are `type-hints` for run-time validation. It tells the code to expect objects of class type `campaignDTO` and `ParamDTO`, or a class that extends from these.

If you pass in an array, or a string, or something that is not a class that is or extends `capaignDTO` then the code will throw an error.

The function, as it is, returns nothing.

According to the code-comment, it will return an object of type `campaignDTO`, which looks like the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so you mean there should be a class named "campaignDTO" somewhere in the code?

Question 2, Is it possible to use a namespace instead of a class for data type?